# Ajax POST request not working after allowing origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://some-api.com/endpoint/",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: '"data": "20200312',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

I've tried almost everything, but for some reason I keep getting the same error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://some-api.com/endpoint/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

What am I doing wrong or missing. I am using Django as my backend. Also it works in Postman, but doesn't work through Ajax

Comment: does your server have `cors` enabled?

Comment: `Access-control-allow-origin` is a response header sent by the server, not a request header.

Comment: Also, your data is not valid JSON. To send JSON, it should be `data: JSON.stringify({data: "20200312"})`

Comment: @messerbill Yes, I followed these steps: http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/python/enable_cors_for_django.aspx  and I still get the same error

Comment: @Barmar I am sure I have that on, I'm using Django and just followed this tutorial http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/python/enable_cors_for_django.aspx

Comment: The error message clearly says that the server didn't send the header. You should be able to verify it in the Network tab of the browser.

Comment: @Barmar In the request headers, it looks like this in the network tab: `Accept: */*`

Comment: That's a request header, I'm talking about the response headers to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, I don't see that header...

Comment: Which is the problem that the error is complaining about. Whatever you did with Django didn't properly enable CORS headers.

Comment: @Barmar So let me give you a bit more background. I'm developing locally trying to access an API on my company's VPN. Would I need to enable CORS headers on my Django app to access this api or would the API application need to add this to give me access?

Comment: It needs to be enabled on `some-api.com`. CORS is just between the browser and the server.

Comment: @Barmar I see, for a temporary solution I was trying to use that Chrome plugin, but whenever I use it, I get this error: `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Comment: @Barmar But it works on Get requests for elasticsearch on our company server for example, but not this post request

Comment: Your company servers are probably in your same domain, CORS is only in effect when you try to access an API in a different domain.

Comment: @Barmar Even though I'm accessing it from local?

Comment: Maybe your company servers are sending CORS headers to allow it.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, if that were the case, then wouldn't I not receive the errors?

Comment: Different applications can send different headers.

Comment: @Barmar I see... that means the only way really is to enable CORS for my application on that api

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.